# FullSimplify a trigonometric expression doesn't work as expected

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, assumptions, trigonometry

I know this kind of question is frequent asked, yet each case has its own particularities. I will show my problem.

I define the following:

```
f[k_] := Binomial[n, k] (Sin[Φ]^2)^k (Cos[Φ]^2)^(n - k);
g[k_] := 2 (f[n - k - 1] (k + 1) - f[n - k] k);
```

After that I want to perform the sum:

```
FullSimplify[Tan[Φ]^2*Sum[g[k]^2/f[n - k], {k, 0, n}],
Element[n, Integers] && n > 0 && Element[Φ, Reals] && 0 < Φ < Pi/2]
```

And I got the result:

```
4 n^2 Cos[Φ]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{-n,1-n/2-1/2 n Cos[2 Φ],1-n/2- 
1/2 n Cos[2 Φ]},{-n Cos[Φ]^2,-n Cos[Φ]^2},-Cot[Φ]^2] Sin[Φ]^(-2+2 n)
```

This as much as I can simplify the expression. However, according to book the result of the sum is just 4n

```
H[n_]=Tan[Φ]^2*Sum[g[k]^2/f[n - k], {k, 0, n}]]//FullSimplify

Table[H[i],{i,1,10}]//FullSimplify
{4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40}
```

If I introduce the Assumptions in the following way at the beginning of the notebook:

```
$Assumptions = n ∈ Integers && n < 100 && 
  n > 0 && Φ ∈ Reals && 0 < Φ < Pi/2
```

The result of the simplification is yet worse.

The problem is that I have to perform some summations similar to this, but this time I don't have previous knowledge of the solution

Answer (score 4):

Eliminating the trigonometric terms work in this case:

```
expr = 4 n^2 Cos[Φ]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{-n,1-n/2-1/2 n Cos[2 Φ],1-n/2- 
  1/2 n Cos[2 Φ]},{-n Cos[Φ]^2,-n Cos[Φ]^2},-Cot[Φ]^2] Sin[Φ]^(-2+2 n);

FullSimplify[expr /. Φ -> ArcCos[q], 0 < q < 1]
```

> ```
> 4n
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

$Assumptions =
  Element[n, Integers] && n > 0 && 0 < Φ < Pi/2;

f[k_] := Binomial[n, k] (Sin[Φ]^2)^
    k (Cos[Φ]^2)^(n - k);
g[k_] := 2 (f[n - k - 1] (k + 1) - f[n - k] k);

seq = Table[
  Tan[Φ]^2*Sum[g[k]^2/f[n - k], {k, 0, n}] // Simplify,
  {n, 1, 10}]

(* {4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40} *)
```

Using [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html),

```
H[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]

(* 4 n *)
```

Verifying over wider range,

```
And @@ Table[
  H[n] == Tan[Φ]^2*Sum[g[k]^2/f[n - k], {k, 0, n}] // Simplify, {n,
    1, 25}]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank, that's very useful answer. That function may be helpful